# Using Hibernate entity manager but connection is not closed and memory is not release

Tags: java, hibernate

I found out that em.close() and emf.close() are not closing the connection, seeing the memory is not resealed.

There are two related posts about session, but not entity manager.
[How to force hibernate to release memory once the session is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928366/how-to-force-hibernate-to-release-memory-once-the-session-is-closed)
[Closing Hibernate Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427976/closing-hibernate-connection)

Is there any example that closing the connection in the correct way?

```
public class EntityManagerHelper {

private static final EntityManagerFactory emf;

static {
    // pass those parameters via JVM properties or environment variables
    final Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",
            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PG_PASSWORD"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("PG_PASSWORD is not provided")));
    config.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user",
            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PG_USER"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("PG_USER is not provided")));
    final String fullURL = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PG_CONNECTION_STRING"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("PG_CONNECTION_STRING is not provided"));
    config.put("javax.persistence.jdb.url", fullURL);
    config.put("hibernate.connection.url", fullURL);
    config.put("connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3");

    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size",
            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("POOL_MIN_SIZE")).orElse("1"));
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size",
            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("POOL_MAX_SIZE")).orElse("1"));
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout",
            Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("TIMEOUT")).orElse("0"));

    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts", "1");
    config.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay", "250");

    config.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    config.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
    config.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory");
    config.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

    config.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    config.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    config.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    config.put("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/ehcacheAdmin.xml");
    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ConfigPersistence", config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    try {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
    emf.close();
}

public static void beginTransaction() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
}

public static void rollback() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
}

public static void commit() {
    getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

}

**EDIT**:
currently it's read-only.
The memory issue comes when

```
entityManager = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();
            fooConf = entityManager.find(Foo.class, fooId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking all the methods always on a new instance of `entityManger`. This could never work..

Do not use static methods for manipulating the entityManager but do it directly in the transactional method. Just use the static util method to get the manager:

```
EntityManager em =  EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();

try{
  em.getTransaction().begin();

  // operations

  em.getTransaction().commit();
} catch(Exception e){
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally{
   em.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is an issue, but the problem is not the transaction methods yet because they are not called. I will edit my question.

Comment: Ok so even when you call entityManager.close(); after that find method.. its stil openend?

Comment: I remove all static and I cannot find the connection is opened, but the memory is still not released.

Comment: are you sure you are calling entityManager.close() after the query?